# Android 4.4 KitKat random crash (Native crash at /system/lib/libc.so)

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat, android-youtube-api

I built an app that plays YouTube iframe video via WebView and controls video with YouTube iframe api.

(I know that YouTube SDK for Android may be more recommended for Android app development, but for now only iframe api fits our need)

I found out that the app randomly crashes when running under Android 4.4 KitKat.

This is the complete crash log from Google Play console:

```
Native crash at /system/lib/libc.so
in /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12), /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)

*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/lt02ltespr/lt02ltespr:4.4.2/KOT49H/T217SVPUBNH4:user/release-keys'
Revision: '9'
pid: 10404, tid: 10660, name: rbbb.myapp >>> com.kkkkrbbb.myapp <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
r0 00000000 r1 000029a4 r2 00000006 r3 00000000
r4 00000006 r5 00000000 r6 000029a4 r7 0000010c
r8 630b10d0 r9 578211e8 sl 576f7830 fp 57821058
ip 4016f394 sp 6b8df9e8 lr 4013419d pc 40143144 cpsr 000b0010
d0 64207461090a2939 d1 79732e6b69766c61
d2 74614e2e6d657473 d3 7472617453657669
d4 031c01f305bb0022 d5 017009920185050a
d6 fe160e5fffb70c29 d7 fe98145bffc7133e
d8 3f8000003f800000 d9 4298000000000000
d10 00000000420c0000 d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 74614e286e75722e d17 6874654d20657669
d18 656c65722e656764 d19 757074754f657361
d20 2872656666754274 d21 646f43616964654d
d22 6567646972426365 d23 38313a6176616a2e
d24 3ff89499f93ebf0f d25 400921fb54442d18
d26 bfadde2f1100f60a d27 3fa97b4beb58fff5
d28 3f90ad3ae322da11 d29 3f53891194985e55
d30 3fd555562f68cf9d d31 bfc9999aecd3aacb
scr 28000013

backtrace:
#00 pc 00022144 /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01 pc 00013199 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
#02 pc 000133ad /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
#03 pc 000120e3 /system/lib/libc.so
#04 pc 000219f8 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#05 pc 001c46f9 /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#06 pc 001c1c9b /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#07 pc 00afcb27 /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#08 pc 00afc40b /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#09 pc 001cf24f /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#10 pc 001cfd51 /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#11 pc 001cfeaf /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#12 pc 001cffbd /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#13 pc 001cf575 /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#14 pc 001d403f /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#15 pc 001cedaf /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#16 pc 001dc42d /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#17 pc 001da25b /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#18 pc 0000d288 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#19 pc 0000d420 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)

code around pc:
40143124 e8bd00f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000 
40143134 ea006e4f e92d50f0 e3a07f43 ef000000 
40143144 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000 
40143154 ea006e47 e92d50f0 e3a070ee ef000000 
40143164 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000 
40143174 ea006e3f f200429a bf0080b9 f040f891 
40143184 4001e92d f2c02a04 2a1080a5 8093f2c0 
40143194 f2c02a20 2a408088 ea4fdb7f f1bc1c92 
401431a4 dd6c0f0a 0600e92d 0f40f1bc f500dd4a 
401431b4 f5016e80 ebae7920 ea4f0e09 ea4f5e4e 
401431c4 f50e5e5e ebbc7e20 dd3b1f9e f04fbfc4 
401431d4 ebd9090a dd35199e 0a0eeb01 0a3ff02a 
401431e4 1c9eebac bfd245e1 0c09ebac f04f46e1 
401431f4 f8910c00 f891f240 f921f280 f921028d 
40143204 f8da428d f1b93000 f9000901 f900028d 
40143214 f10a428d d1ee0a40 0f00f1bc f5bcd02b 

code around lr:
4013417c 447b4b13 42b3e010 6a1ed10e 44784811 
4013418c ec84f7fb ea0cf00d 46224631 efcef00e 
4013419c d00a3001 e00b2400 2b00681b 480ad1eb 
401341ac 44782403 ec72f7fb f001e002 6804fa23 
401341bc fa20f001 46206005 bf00bd70 0003b236 
401341cc 0003b22a 0003b222 0003b1fe bf7ef7ff 
401341dc 4a3e4b3d e92d447b b08b43f0 4606589c 
401341ec 6823460d 930946a1 fa04f001 8000f8d0 
401341fc d0482d00 f0104628 280ff889 d8444604 
4013420c ffe4f7ff d1064286 4629200f e8d6f00d 
4013421c d03c2800 482ee02e f7fb4478 482debb6 
4013422c e0154478 d11342b0 482b6a06 f7fb4478 
4013423c 4a2aec2e 46332120 a801447a f92af013 
4013424c a8012101 fc48f01a 46061c42 e011d104 
4013425c 28006800 e02cd1e6 46294630 f00d4622 
4013426c 1c43e912 d11e4607 f9c4f001 29046801
```

And feedbacks from users are "It won't stop after I press stop button" and "It accidentally stopped".

Since this problem randomly happens, I cannot reproduce it and yet don't know how to fix it.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: From the report, it's a KitKat 4.4.2 (KOT49H), probably running with ART, some Chrome tread, probably from a webview in your app. To be honest, since ART is experimental and all that, I would report it on Google support forums, https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/art.html#Reporting_Problems

Comment: I just received a similar looking crash report, but my backtrace doesn't include libwebviewchromium.so and does include libdvm.so (dalvik vm), so it's definitely not running ART.

It's quite strange. My app doesn't have any native code, nor does it do any drawing, bitmap loading or animations. It must be a bug in the samsung OS.

Comment: Same here from an Android 4.4 device.

Comment: Any solution to this issue ?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I still see this one from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are trying to display a **corrupted JPEG file**. Try to open them all and see if there isn't one that fails to load.